# Chrome returns "duplicate headers received from server"

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Here is some additional info to answer questions in comments:

1. This is a private website that requires login and password. Unfortunately, I cannot provide this info for security reasons.
2. What you see is the part of 300 lines script. It does the following: go to the URL, login to the page, browse to the specific page, from a dropdown read the list of files, change dropdown selection for each account and download the file. Keep doing so until all files are downloaded.
3. The website has a large number of files. Currently the script is able to download 30+ files. It is failing at the same file on every run.
4. Please let me know if you have any more questions.

I have a script that is downloading multiple files from a website.

I have received the following error in Chrome:

> duplicate headers received from server

I searched the web and it seems that the file name specified needs to be in quotes. Unfortunately, I do not specify the file name when downloading the files, so I am not sure how to get around this.

Here are some parts of the code I am using:

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new(autopick: true, reuse: false, destroy_at_exit: true).start

prefs = {
  :download => {
    :prompt_for_download => false,
    :default_directory => path['xdrive']
  },
  :profile => {
    :content_settings => {
                            :pattern_pairs => {
                                                :* => {
                                                        :'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1
                                                      }
                            }
                         }
  }
}
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 60 # seconds - default is 60
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :prefs => prefs, :http_client => client, :switches => %w[--disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]
b = Watir::Browser.new d

@myLinks.each { |option|
    puts "Getting " + option[:text]
    b.select_list(:id, "someField").select_value(option[:value])
    sleep 6

    b.goto "https://www.somewebsite.com/DownloadFile.ashx"
    sleep 1
}
```

Comment: Could you use a http client instead of webdriver for this? e.g.

    require "httparty"
    
    File.open("/tmp/filename.ext", "wb") do |f| 
      f.write HTTParty.get("https://www.somewebsite.com/DownloadFile.ashx").parsed_response
    end

Comment: The script is 300+ lines of code with authentication and other actions. I only provided the parts of the script that do downloading.

Comment: What line of code is being executed when the error occurs?   What does @myLinks contain? Maybe some code is missing, or there is a default site when the browser opens, but  I see the browser being told to select an option from a select list before any navigation has occurred, so it is difficult to understand what page the browser is on at that point in the script.   I understand you might be trying to protect IP or the exact work you are doing, but unfortunately that also makes if very difficult for us to assist you because we can't really tell what your code is doing.

Comment: @myLinks contains the list from a drop-down menu. After that, I go through the list and download files. When I select each option on a drop-down, an ajax (I think) request refreshes the content of the page and clicking on the link downloads files. The code does download some files, but then fails. This is a secure website that requires login and password. I did not include that code since it does not seem relevant.

Comment: Still not able to find a solution...

Comment: You can use `curl -I http://example.com` to see the headers and look for duplicates, or you can load the page in Google Chrome when the developer tools are open to see the headers.  It would really help if you could provide a minimal script that reproduces the problem though.  Also, I don't understand what page you are viewing in Google Chrome; could you explain how you reproduce the bug?  Better yet, provide some instructions that other people can follow to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am updating my ticket to answer the questions.

Comment: You mention that the problem occurs with a specific file. What is the difference between that file and the others?

Comment: I figured it out with your hint Justin! Apparently, there is a comma in the account name of the file that is being download it and it is causing Chrome to choke. The issue is it is not actually dying on the file with comma, but on the next file. Once, the comma was removed everything is working great!

Answer (score 0):

See comments to the original question

Based on a question asked by @Justin Ko, The poster found that there was account name data containing a comma which was causing the error.  removing the comma from his fixture data fixed his issue.